# start_symbol_ticker_socket() no callback to my callable function

Tags: python, api

I'm try to use `start_symbol_ticker_socket()` to create a thread for print latest price automatically. But when I implement my code, nothing to happen and without any Error Message.

This is my code.

```
from binance.client import Client
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep, time
from binance import ThreadedWebsocketManager


def ReadKeySecret():
    f = open('BNAPI_TEST.txt','r')
    api_key = f.read()
    f = open('BNST_TEST.txt','r')
    api_secret = f.read()
    return api_key, api_secret


def btc_trade_history(msg):
    btc_price = {'error':False}
    if msg['e'] != 'error':
        print(msg)
        btc_price['last'] = msg['c']
        btc_price['bid'] = msg['b']
        btc_price['best'] = msg['a']
        btc_price['error'] = False
    else:
        btc_price['error'] = True

def GetNewPrice(API_KEY,API_SECRET):   #test by BTCUSDT
    bsm = ThreadedWebsocketManager(API_KEY,API_SECRET)
    bsm.start()
    bsm.start_symbol_ticker_socket(callback =btc_trade_history, symbol='BTCUSDT')
    sleep(2)
    bsm.stop()


API_KEY,API_SECRET = ReadKeySecret()
client = Client(API_KEY,API_SECRET)
client.API_URL = 'https://testnet.binance.vision/api'
GetNewPrice(API_KEY,API_SECRET)
```

I can using `client.get_symbol_ticker(symbol="BTCUSDT")` to get BTC price.

can give me any suggestion? thanks.

Comment: At the moment you're not using client at all - you just make an instance but never actually perform a call to any of the mentioned methods.

Comment: @rammelmueller now I can get msg about start_symbol_ticker_socket() callback, but I didn't edit anything about my code. I guess that the request maybe blocked by network. After I change my net, It's working normal. Thanks your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd encountered the same issue. After a couple of day investigating, I found out that there are issues with the threading handler of the python-binance 1.0.16 (maybe compatibility issues with python 3.10)

There are also topics about that issue here:

- https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/1174
- https://github.com/sammchardy/python-binance/issues/1172

My best workaround for now is to downgrade python-binance to 1.0.15 and use python 3.9 instead of 3.10.